# Uniq value in option_from_collection_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How i can print only unique value in **options_from_collection_for_select()** helper ?
Because i don't want to have 10 times the same value...

```
 <%= select_tag :type, options_from_collection_for_select(
 Course.where(category_id: @category.id), 
 :learning_type, 
 :learning_type, 
 @type)
 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. Let's say you have **Course** model, and you want to show the uniq **learning_type** of the course. You can get the results as an array with something like:

```
Course.where(category_id: @category.id).pluck(:learning_type).uniq
```

or

```
Course.where(category_id: @category.id).pluck('DISTINCT learning_type')
```

It's always better to use Fat model and use scopes in your Course model thought.

Now you can easily use the array with that form helper, something like:

```
<%= select_tag :type, options_for_select(Course.where(category_id: @category.id).pluck('DISTINCT learning_type')) %>
```